# Generate two different random number lists

Tags: python, list, random

I want to generate two differnt random number lists.
The condition is the value of the first list index cannot be equal to the second list value in the same index.

For example `a=[5,6,7,5]` and `q=[2,7,3,5]` in this case the value of the fourth index in list q is equal to the value in the same index in list a. I want to avoid this. I created list a as folllowing

```
import random
a=[]
b=list(range(1,7164))
for i in b:
   t=random.randint(1,20)
   a.append(t)
```

how to generate the second list with above condition?

Comment: can you add an expected output

Comment: just check "if i==t" and if this is True - generate another int until condition is False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates `a` and `q` as tuples, but you can easily convert them to lists.

```
In [29]: import random                                                                                                                   

In [30]: size = 15                                                                                                                       

In [31]: maxval = 20                                                                                                                     

In [32]: a, q = zip(*[random.sample(range(1, maxval+1), 2) for z in range(size)])         

In [33]: a                                                                                                                               
Out[33]: (18, 7, 12, 6, 17, 16, 12, 1, 14, 20, 9, 5, 8, 5, 18)

In [34]: q                                                                                                                               
Out[34]: (12, 10, 6, 1, 12, 15, 20, 7, 6, 10, 5, 7, 16, 7, 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import random

def generate_n_lists(num_of_lists, num_of_elements, value_from=0, value_to=100):
    s = random.sample(range(value_from, value_to + 1), num_of_lists * num_of_elements)
    return [s[i*num_of_elements:(i+1)*num_of_elements] for i in range(num_of_lists)]

print(generate_n_lists(2, 5, 0, 20))    # generate 2 lists, each 5 elements, values are from 0 to 20
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 16, 4, 3, 15], [0, 10, 14, 17, 7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The best approach I think would be is to iterate over each item and offset it with a random number in a way that it can't be the same as the original value.
Add the following to the end of your code:

```
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    t = (a[i] + random.randint(1, 19)) % 19 + 1
    c.append(t)
```

This way you offset each of the items with a number between 1-18, and wrap it around if it goes above 19. (+1 so it's between 1 and 19, not 0)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid it, just check if it is repeating. If it is, generate a different random number again.

```
import random
a=[]
b=list(range(1,7164))
for i in b:
    t=random.randint(1,20)
    while t == i:
        t = random.randint(1,20)
    a.append(t)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.

One would be to generate the second random value in a smaller range, and offset if it equals or exceeds the excluded value:

```
excluded_value = first_list[i]
new_value = random.randint(1, 19)
if new_value >= excluded_value:
    new_value += 1
```

Another is to generate the lists at the same time, using [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to select without replacement.

```
possible_values = range(1, 20) # or xrange on python 2.x
while i < desired_num_values:
    a, b = random.sample(possible_values, 2)
    first_list.append(a)
    second_list.append(b)
    i += 1
```

I have not profiled to see if there's a notable performance difference. Both seem likely to be faster than repeatedly generating a random number until there isn't a conflict (but again, I haven't profiled to confirm). The second scales more gracefully if you want more than two lists.

These are not the only ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
a=[]
b=[]
for rand_a in range(1,7164):
    a.append(random.randint(1,20))

random.seed()
for rand_b in range(1,7164):
    r = random.randint(1,20)
    # keep rolling until you get a diff number
    while (a[rand_b] == r):
        r = random.randint(1,20)
    b.append(r)
```

your code example had 1 random list and 1 list of 1,7164.
This code will generate you two lists of 1,20 with a total of 17164 elements all of differing values based on their respective position in the other list.
seed probably isn't needed but